# Disable Popups while Refreshing PowerQuery using VBA

Tags: python, powerquery

I am having 6 excel files that are refreshed based on one `json`. Every `json` will not have data for all the 6 excel file. I need some way to remove this pop-up so that I could automate the process.

[image]

How shall I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Post your 'EXP' query code.

Comment: That sounds like an error from the PQ code (hard-coded column name?). If a column name may change or if the number of columns might shift, you may need to look into more generic/relative code to keep the PQ code from error-ing out.